# Visual studio 2022 / Resharper indents element after new line

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2022

I have some code in visual studio that looks like this:
[image]

if I place my cursor at the end of the div with class "row" and press enter, that whole div loses its indentation and goes to start like this:

[image]

It has been driving me mad because I can't figure out what does it nor how to stop it. I have visual studio 2022 and I also have Resharper installed.

I'm fairly confident it has something to do with resharper, I just can't figure out what. If I disable resharper then this problem goes away. Resharper is updated to latest version.

Comment: Did you analyze/play around with your HTML code style settings within R#? Probably that's a good starting point

Answer (score 3):

Only solution I came up with was to turn off auto-formatting after pressing Enter (for Razor files).

(untick Resharper -> Options -> Behaviour -> Razor -> Auto-format on Enter)

Comment: I just had to do this as well. I cannot say for sure whether or not this was a problem in the previous version of R#, but based on changes I've made to the same cshtml files in the history of the repo without encountering it I'm inclined to say this is a new bug with the latest R#.